# Realm createOrUpdateAllFromJson to create RealmModel objects without persisting?

Tags: java, android, json, realm, realm-java

I'm using realm Java in my in-development Android app quite happily. I receive `JSONObject` arrays from the server API, and realm dutifully ingests them through the convenient `createOrUpdateAllFromJson` on the main realm instance object.

The typical flow for this looks like:

```
// get API results into JSONArray jsonObjArrs variable
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(MyCoolModel.class,jsonObjArrs);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

However, I've now run into a situation where I would like to create a temporary, in-memory array of the same `MyCoolModel` objects **without** actually saving them to Realm, because I want to throw these away as soon as the specific use case is done. It looks to me like `createOrUpdateAllFromJson` and its sibling methods are only available on the main realm instance object.

Is there any way to harness this convenient `JSON` to object model creator, or do I have to write an alternate implementation with manual / automated JSON parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the "In memory Realm" feature of realm. I wrote a simple function that would return a new in-memory realm instance, with a new UUID as a name:

```
public Realm unpersistedRealm(){
    RealmConfiguration myConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .inMemory()
            .build();
    return Realm.getInstance(myConfig);
}
```

I use this as a separately created instance just for throw-away data purposes. I create the objects using the normal `inMemoryRealmInstance.createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` call and close the in memory instance the moment I'm done. I create the instance during my fragment's `onCreateView()` call and close the realm in `onDestroyView()`.

Continuing to use realm (albeit an in-memory instance) gives me the following distinct advantages:

- In built de-duplication using @PrimaryKey on my `MyCoolModel` key field. If I were to use the manual `ArrayList<MyCoolModel>` approach that I was earlier thinking of, I'd have to manually de-duplicate, and worry about other headaches that Realm already solved for me.
- Query based sorting, filtering, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want in-memory objects from a JSON structure, your should look at a standard JSON parser like GSON, Jackson or Moshi. Realm does not have any inbuilt way of doing this.

Comment: Any thoughts on my solution of using the In Memory Realm feature? How would this compare to using an ArrayList instead?

Answer (score 1):

A ridiculously hacky solution would be

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(MyCoolModel.class,jsonObjArrs);
List<MyCoolModel> list = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(MyCoolModel.class)).findAll());
realm.cancelTransaction();
return list;
```

But you're better off with using LoganSquare (or GSON/Moshi/etc)